# How do I calculate the difference in days between two ISO8601 dates with Freemarker?

Tags: datetime, freemarker

I have an object in Freemarker which has dates in ISO8601 format (e.g. `2012-02-01T13:01:02+0000`), how would I go about working out the difference in days between it and now?

In other non-Java scenarios I'd reformat it as a unix timestamp and do the maths (like the `distance_of_time_in_words` functions in RoR or Symfony), however as far as I can see, Freemarker is unable to turn a  ISO8601 timestamp into unix timestamp.

And yes, I realise the template layer probably isn't the right place to be doing this kind of thing, but needs must etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If by difference in days you mean how many times 24 hours were elapsed between the two dates, then this expression does that (you need at least FreeMarker 2.3.17 for `?long` to work like this):

```
(
  (
    s2?datetime("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")?long
    - s1?datetime("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")?long
  ) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
)?int
```

A nicer approach is to implement the function in Java with implementing `TemplateMethodModelEx`. Templates can pull that in with `<#assign distanceInDays = 'com.example.DistanceInDaysMethod'?new()>` (put this into a commonly `#include`-d or `#import`-ed file) and then you can use it as `distanceInDays(s1, s2)`.

Comment: What does the `?new()` built-in do? I can't see it in the FM docs