# Error printing dates days diff in Freemarker

Tags: java, date, datetime, freemarker

I am having a problem with freemarker dates.

I want to compare to dates and also print the day diff.
the first date is passed to the model (java.util.Date)
The second one is the freemarker `.now` var.

So I am doing this:

```
<#assign currentDate = .now>
<#if currentDate?long < trip.endDate?long> <#-- Not ended -->
```

This is working fine, but then when I try to get the day diff, as stated here: [How do I calculate the difference in days between two ISO8601 dates with Freemarker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412040/how-do-i-calculate-the-difference-in-days-between-two-iso8601-dates-with-freemar)

I am doing:

```
<#assign currentDate = .now>
${((trip.startDate?datetime("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")?long - currentDate?datetime("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")?long) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))?int}
```

And this is throwing:

`Expected method. trip.startDate?datetime evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleDate`

Then I tryied adding `?date` as I saw that some do that in order to get the right type of the object, like this

```
<#assign currentDate = .now>
${((trip.startDate?date?datetime("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")?long - currentDate?datetime("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")?long) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))?int}
```

And it throws:

`Cannot convert DATE into DATETIME`

Just to make sure that the object I am using is `java.util.Date`, here is my Trip class:

```
package com.test.planner.dto;

import java.util.Date;

public class Trip
    implements Comparable<Trip> {

    private Date startDate; // start date
    private Date endDate; // end date

    // ...

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return this.startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Date getEndDate() {
        return this.endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Trip o) {
        return this.getStartDate().compareTo(o.getStartDate());
    }
}
```

And I am passing this to the model:

```
Trip trip = new Trip();
trip.setStartDate(new Date(1410318000000L)); // Wed Sep 10 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)
trip.setEndDate(new Date(1410318000000L + 691200000L)); // Plus 8 days

mav.addObject("trip", trip);
```

Comment: Why do you calling `?datetime`?

Comment: Because is stated in the link I provided: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412040/how-do-i-calculate-the-difference-in-days-between-two-iso8601-dates-with-freemar
Is that wrong?

Comment: In that link dates are in the specific format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo?datetime("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")` meant to be used when `foo` is a string (that also have the given format). Then it will convert the `String` to a `java.util.Date`. But `.now` is already `java.util.Date`, so you don't need to and can't convert it with a pattern. Only strings has to be converted like that. Then both can be `?long`-ed, and there you go.

For future readers: Starting from 2.3.21 you should convert ISO 8601 string to date-time like `foo?datetime.iso`. Not just because it's more convenient, but because ISO 8601 allows quite a few date-time format patterns, and of course it's impossible to cover all of them with a single pattern. `?datetime.iso` takes care of that problem.

Comment: I got it now, I just missunderstood the purpose of `?datetime` .. It just has a ver confusing name..